# Why does not thread join?

Tags: java, multithreading, join, concurrency

I want to measure thread execution

I wrote following code:

```
public class Task5 {
    public static int [] readerThreadCount = {10};
    public static int [] writerThreadCount = {1};


    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        for (int readCount : readerThreadCount) {
            for (int writeCount : writerThreadCount) {
                test(readCount, writeCount, new ArrayHolderBySynchronized());
            }
        }

    }

    private static void test(int readCount, int writeCount, ArrayHolder arrayHolder) throws InterruptedException {
        final List<Thread> threads = new ArrayList<>();
        CyclicBarrier cyclicBarrier = new CyclicBarrier(1, new Summarizer(threads, readCount, writeCount));
        for (int i = 0; i < readCount; i++) {
            threads.add(new Thread(new ArrayReader(arrayHolder, cyclicBarrier)));
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < writeCount; i++) {
            threads.add(new Thread(new ArrayWriter(arrayHolder, cyclicBarrier)));

        }

        for(Thread thread:threads){
            thread.start();
        }

    }
}

class Summarizer implements Runnable{
    List<Thread> threads;
    int readCount;
    int writeCount;
    Summarizer(List<Thread> threads, int readCount, int writeCount) {
        this.threads = threads;
        this.readCount = readCount;
        this.writeCount = writeCount;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println("All threads started");
        for (Thread thread : threads) {
            try {
                thread.join();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();  //To change body of catch statement use File | Settings | File Templates.
            }
        }
        System.out.println(readCount + "/" + writeCount + (System.currentTimeMillis() - start));
    }
}
class ArrayHolderBySynchronized extends ArrayHolder {

    @Override
    public synchronized int get(int index) {
        System.out.println("read");
        return arr[index];
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized void write(int index, int value) {
        System.out.println("write");
        arr[index] = value;
    }
}

class ArrayReader implements Runnable {
    ArrayHolder arrayHolder;
    CyclicBarrier cyclicBarrier;

    ArrayReader(ArrayHolder arrayHolder, CyclicBarrier cyclicBarrier) {
        this.arrayHolder = arrayHolder;
        this.cyclicBarrier = cyclicBarrier;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            cyclicBarrier.await();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();  //To change body of catch statement use File | Settings | File Templates.
        } catch (BrokenBarrierException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();  //To change body of catch statement use File | Settings | File Templates.
        }
        arrayHolder.get(new Random().nextInt(ArrayHolder.ARRAY_SIZE));
    }
}

class ArrayWriter implements Runnable {
    ArrayHolder arrayHolder;
    CyclicBarrier cyclicBarrier;

    ArrayWriter(ArrayHolder arrayHolder, CyclicBarrier cyclicBarrier) {
        this.arrayHolder = arrayHolder;
        this.cyclicBarrier = cyclicBarrier;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            cyclicBarrier.await();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();  //To change body of catch statement use File | Settings | File Templates.
        } catch (BrokenBarrierException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();  //To change body of catch statement use File | Settings | File Templates.
        }
        arrayHolder.write(new Random().nextInt(ArrayHolder.ARRAY_SIZE), -1);
    }
}

abstract class ArrayHolder {
    public static int ARRAY_SIZE = 1_000_000;
    protected int[] arr = generateArray();

    private int[] generateArray() {
        int[] arr = new int[ARRAY_SIZE];
        for (int i = 0; i < ARRAY_SIZE; i++) {
            arr[i] = i + 1;
        }
        return arr;
    }

    public abstract int get(int index);

    public abstract void write(int index, int value);
}
```

but in output I see

```
All threads started
```

But appication hangs on thread.join.

What do I wrong?

Comment: What does "measure thread execution" mean?  Your example looks _very_ complicated.

Answer (score 0):

You have a deadlock in your code:

You are submitting the Summarizer instance as barrierAction to the CyclicBarrier. So when barrier trips it has to execute the Summarizer before any thread awaiting on the barrier is allowed to proceed. **But** the Summarizer performs thread.join() on all threads that awaiting on that CyclicBarrier.

So the CyclicBarrier is waiting for the Summarizer. The Summarizer is waiting for the threads. And threads are waiting for the CyclicBarrier.